# Android: Unable to instantiate application

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I renamed my package and now I get this strange error:

```
Unable to instantiate application
app.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
app.MyApplication in loaderdalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

The `MyApplication` class is in `Application/app`. The Manifest says:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="Application">
```

```xml
<application 
    android:label="AGG"
    android:name="app.MyApplication"...
```

I tried restart, clean built. Is doesn't work on an emulator nor on a real device.

What on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's assume, that your projects base package is really `Application`, as you've stated it in the `manifest`.

If your `MyApplication` class is inside this package (the package declaration of the class is `package Application;`), then the `application` element in your `androidManifest.xml` should look like

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication" [...]
```

If this `MyApplication` class is inside the `Application.app` package (`package Application.app;`), then in the manifest you should write:

```
<application android:name=".app.MyApplication" [...]
```

If you didn't extend the `android.app.Application` (you don't have a `MyApplication extends android.app.Application` class), just wanted to set a name to your application, remove it this attribute, since it says to the compiler that there is an `Application` extension that should be instantiated instead of the default `android.app.Application`.

And finally, if the first assumption is wrong, and you've changed for any reason the package declaration in your androidManifest's `manifest` element, undo it or update your classes to be in that package.

Comment: your are correct. i had a custom android.app.Application (MyApplication). What i forgot was the leading `.` prior to `app.MyApplication`

Comment: I'm glad you've made it, happy coding further!

Comment: @MichałK +1 for the comment above, Eclipse restart worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

For me, the issue was with instant-run. Disabling it solved the issue.

Will update if I find a solution for re-enabling and making it work.

Comment: Android Studio team still didn't fix this issue

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Instant run was creating issue.

Comment: For disabling instant run -> Settings and write instant run

Comment: Weird...for me it was enabling instant run

Answer (score 6):

In my case it throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<foo.bar.MyApp> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
```

The reason is **the Application class must be declared with the modifier `public`**, e.g. do this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
}
```

instead of:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this answer helped me, basically rename your lib to libs if you're using SDK 17+
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176048/46459

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I've change JAVA compiler compliance level from 1.7 to 1.6 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

make sure all references in your manifest have been updated to reflect your new package name.

Answer (score 1):

Should `package="Application"` be `package="MyApplication"`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the `android:name` attribute. Same problem mentioned at [ClassNotFoundException after changing app's name in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407201/classnotfoundexception-after-changing-apps-name-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

what works for me is changing these lines in build.gradle:

```
anotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
anotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hiltVersion"
```

to:

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hiltVersion"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: 1. Read the question (yes, all of it)
2. This question was answered literally years ago
3. Welcome to SE

Comment: It's works for me. My project has modify nothing, it happen suddenly. After delete the build folder, and run again, the problem solved. It's a bug of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these lines worked for me:

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**Update:**
The reason behind this issue is that i have not installed JAVA 8 on my PC

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was due to access level of the class, it has to be public

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any dependency injection libraries or other third-party libraries that modify application startup, make sure the configuration is correct. Some frameworks require extra settings to work properly.