# AndroidRuntime - Unable to instantiate application on mac os

Tags: java, android, osx-lion, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception

I'm getting the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(1840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> instantiate application com.mypackage.ui.misc.MyApplication:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.ui.misc.MyApplication
> in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk]

My manifest looks like this:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mypackage"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">
...
    <application
        android:name=".ui.misc.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" > 
...
```

I should mention that this is happening on Mac OS X Lion. I've tried to run the app both on an emulator and a couple of Android devices and if always failed with the same error.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859261/android-unable-to-instantiate-application) solution, but my class is located at com.mypackage.ui.misc.MyApplication and it extends android.app.Application so it doesn't apply.

Anybody else ran into this weird error? Any ideas on how to fix it?

**UPDATE**:
Ran into the same problem on Ubuntu, with the same project.

Comment: I understand that this is stupid, but I have to ask - are you sure, that your class name and package are the same in java file and in manifest? Because I use the same, and I'm also on Lion - and I don't see any problems with custom `Application` class

Comment: There's not idea stupid enough to mention. I wish the solution would be that simple. I've checked the names multiple times, but that's not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turnes out the problem I was having had to do with a couple of libraries I was using. The libraries were included in the Java Build Path but not in the Android references.
Adding them as references to the Android properties fixed the problem:

Right-click on the project -> choose Properties -> click on Android -> add the libraries in the Libraries section.