# Simple android application with roboguice throwing exceptions

Tags: android, roboguice

I have a very simple application that works but when i add roboguice it throws

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.MyFirstApp.MyFirstApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.MyFirstApp.MyFirstApplication

The application class:

```
public class MyFirstApplication extends RoboApplication {

    @Override
    protected void addApplicationModules(List<Module> modules) {
        //modules.add(new DefaultModule());
    }
}
```

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

the manifest:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MyFirstApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="MyFirstApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyFirstApp.Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have put guice-2.0-no_aop.jar and roboguice-1.1.3.jar in the assets folder and added them to the buildpath.

when i remove the robo part it works fine. can anyone tell me what i did wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i found out what the problem was. i was using SDK v17+ and in that version external library's need te be placed in a "libs" folder and only in the libs folder. so all the tutorial's i found where they just put it in the assets folder where wrong.

Link to where i got the answer i was looking for: http://groups.google.com/group/roboguice/browse_thread/thread/474116b052050ae2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, extending from `RoboApplication` is a RoboGuice 1.x thing, you should really be using RoboGuice 2.0 (where you no longer need to do that). Now, for your exception, is your Application class really at  `com.MyFirstApp.MyApplication`? If not, you would need to update the `name` attribute to match.

Comment: As i am using 1.1.3 i do need to extend from RoboApplication right?
Also i am 100% sure that is where it is located at.

Comment: Oke, did what you suggested and upgraded to 2.0. the application works. but the activity now throws an error. without RoboActivity it works with it it just says:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.MyFirstApp/com.MyFirstApp.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MyFirstApp.Activities.MainActivity

Comment: Roboguice 2.0 is still in beta.  Why should LordSauron use it?  I gave 2.0 two serious shots, spent several days troubleshooting, and and even after asking for support on the forums the issues remained unresolved.  I'm still using 1.1.1.

Comment: Well, you pretty much *have* to use 2.0 if you want to use Fragments (and if you're just starting, why not?). I'll admit that the upgrade from 1.1 was a bit of a pain, but it was definitely worth it.